# Concerning a 2-variable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

A couple of friends of mine gave a Mathematical Analysis 2 test this morning where they were asked to study continuity and differentiability of the function:

$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \dfrac{xye^{-\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}}}{x^2+2e^{-\frac{2}{(x+y)^2}}} & x\neq-y \\ {} \\0 & x=-y \end{array}\right.$$

Outside $x=-y$ the function is obviously $\mathcal{C}^\infty$. Now we concentrate on continuity. On points $(x_0,-x_0)$, if $x_0\neq0$ one has that the numerator tends to 0 and the denominator tends to $x_0^2$, because the exponentials both tend to 0 and $x^2\to x_0^2$, and $x,y\to x_0$, so the limit is $\frac{x_0^2\cdot0}{x_0^2+0}=0$. But for $x_0=0$? I tried guessing that the exponential on the denominator goes to 0 faster than $x^2$ no matter the path, but Wolfram disagrees and I can't prove otherwise because if I try with polar coordinates I end up with a $\cos\theta$ on the denominator which makes for a $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ which is not bounded, so even though the exponential divided by $\rho^2$ tends to 0, which is because it translates to $e^{-\frac{2}{\rho^2(1+\sin2\theta)}}$ which has $-\infty$ as an exponent, I still have a $0\cdot\infty$ because of that $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$. And even if I prove this limit really is 0, I still end up with $\frac{y}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}}$, and I can't prove this tends to 0 for a similar reason to the above, and Wolfram again says the limit does not exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should first expand the fraction by multypling denominator and numerator by $$e^{\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}}$$ 
If Wolfram says that there is no limit. Try: the substitution $y=m\cdot x$. Then takte the limit for $x \to 0$. If you limit depends on $m$, then the function is not continous in $(x,y)=0$. You might need to use L'Hospitals rule for determining the limit. You can also try other substitutions.

Comment: What's a "limitriable limit"?

Comment: I just tried $y=kx^\alpha$, and obtained that along all such curves both the accessory limits mentioned in the question are 0.

Comment: I'm a bit out of phantasy. Now I'll try $y=k\cdot\log^\alpha(1+x)$.

Comment: @mrf that was Firefox crashing and me retyping the title when it was being loaded :).

Comment: I had «Concerning a 2-variable limit» saved in the draft, but restoring the session the draft took some time to load so I thought the title hadn't been saved and I retyped it, with «On» for «Concerning», and halfway through «variable» the old title reappeared and I typed on, without noticing. In fact, I typed it all before the title was reloaded, but «riable limit» was taken into account only after reloading the old title, and I didn't notice that until now.

Comment: @MJay1985 Assuming it is correct that $e^{-\frac{2}{(x+kx^\alpha)^2}}$ is asymptotic to $e^{-\frac{2}{k^2x^{2\alpha}}}$ when $\alpha<1$ and to $e^{-\frac{2}{x^2}}$ in the other case, then I just found those curves give limit 0, because the exponential on the denominator goes to 0 faster than $x^2$, and getting rid of that exponential gives something with limit 0. Assuming it is true that $e^{-\frac{2}{(x+k\log^\alpha(1+x))^2}}$ is asymptotic to $e^{-\frac{2}{k^2\log^{2\alpha}(1+x)}}$, which in turn is asymptotic to $e^{-\frac{2}{x^{2\alpha}}}$, even these logarithm curves of no use.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing some absolute values there, but I guess putting them in only gives other curves which are again of no use.

Comment: The first asymptotic seems valid if $\alpha<\frac12$. But not for $\alpha\in[\frac12,1]$.

Comment: It is also valid for $\alpha>3$. So the problems are for $\frac12\leq\alpha\leq3$. Then again, for $\alpha\geq1$ the curve has $\theta\not\to\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta\not\to\frac32\pi$, but this is needed to have problems, since by polar coordinates those limits have problems (i.e. could be nonzero) only if $\theta$ tends to one of those values, thus making $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\to\infty$ and thus unbounded, for if that is bounded the exponential tending to 0 eats it up and gives limit 0.

Comment: So we are left with $\alpha\in[\frac12,1]$ to evaluate, and I'm not sure how to take it, since L'Hospital is terrible here. Also, the logarithmic curves are still to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark that for $x+y \neq 0$
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{xy e^{1/(x+y)^2}}{2+x^2 e^{2/(x+y)^2}}.
$$
If we shorten $z=xe^{1/(x+y)^2}$, then
$$
f(x,y)=y \frac{z}{2+z^2}.
$$
Since $z \mapsto z/(2+z^2)$ is a bounded function, we conclude that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: but isn't there a problem with $z$ not beeing defined for $x=-y$?

Comment: No, the estimate is valid as long as $x+y \neq 0$. The bound is independent of $x$ and $y$, so that $$\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ x+y \neq 0}} f(x,y)=0.$$ Along the line $x+y=0$ the function is identically zero.